# Titanium App Crash With a Simple Get Request - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: titanium, httpclient, appcelerator

I am trying to fetch data from a simple get request using `Titanium.Network.HTTPClient`

Here is the code

```
 var url = "http://www.appcelerator.com"; //Here i have my get api URL, i have also tried replacing the url with google.com
 var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
     // function called when the response data is available
     onload : function(e) {
         Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
         alert('success');
     },
     // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
     onerror : function(e) {
         Ti.API.debug(e.error);
         alert('error');
     },
     timeout : 5000  // in milliseconds
 });
 // Prepare the connection.
 client.open("GET", url);
 // Send the request.
 client.send();
```

But the app is crashing with error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extendModel' of undefined`, I am not using any model, It is a new project with the above mentioned code, nothing more.

Here is the screenshot of error

[image: error screenshot]

Please help!

**EDIT**
Configuration details:

- Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 5.0.13
- Titanium SDK
  version 6.0.4.GA
- Node version v4.8.2

Please let me know if any further details required,

Comment: Can you provide the SDK version which you are using. Also does changing the URL to https://www.google.com give the same issue?

Comment: And can you compile it without this code? It looks like alloy isn't setup correctly or missing some files. Maybe a `ti clean` could help

Comment: I will try and let you know guys @Soumya, miga

Comment: @Soumya, i have also tried replacing the url with google.com with no luck, Please find the configuration details above.

Comment: there is only these much code or did you forget something to share?

Comment: I have created a new application/project with a Hello World Label, and pasted the above mentioned code in `onClick` of label. 
App launches and shows the hello world label, but crashes when i tap on it, Also there was some code(which came with template) on `alloy.js` maybe it is used to set up the backbone, I also tried removing the code but no luck.

Comment: Can you try to run the XHR sample from Kitchen Sink and see if that works? Download the latest from Git Hub. If that too does not work, then miga might be correct. A fresh installation might be needed.